# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "venue_city" contains null values

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have read a lot of other posts here on stackoverflow and google but I could not find a solution.

It all started when I changed the model from a CharField to a ForeignKey.
The error I recieve is:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: gis, staticfiles, crispy_forms, geoposition, messages
  Apply all migrations: venues, images, amenities, cities_light, registration, auth, admin, sites, sessions, contenttypes, easy_thumbnails, newsletter
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying venues.0016_auto_20160514_2141...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/venuepark/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "venue_city" contains null values
```

My model is as follows:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True,)
    venue_country=models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
```

venue_country did not exist before so that migration happened successfully. But venue_city was a CharField.

I made some changes to my migration file so that it would execute the sql as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('venues', '0011_venue_map_activation'),
    ]

    migrations.RunSQL(''' ALTER TABLE venues_venue ALTER venue_city TYPE integer USING  venue_city::integer '''),

    migrations.RunSQL(''' ALTER TABLE venues_venue ALTER venue_city RENAME COLUMN venue_city TO venue_city_id '''),

    migrations.RunSQL(''' ALTER TABLE venues_venue ADD CONSTRAINT venues_venus_somefk FOREIGN KEY (venue_city_id) REFERENCES  cities_light (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED'''),
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: my new migration file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('cities_light', '0006_compensate_for_0003_bytestring_bug'),
        ('venues', '0024_remove_venue_venue_city'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='venue',
            name='venue_city',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, to='cities_light.City'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I think, you added `null=True` after created migration file. Because `venue_city ` is not a nullable field in your migration file

Comment: @Anoop how can i fix this? and yes I did.

Comment: which django version you are using?

Comment: If it is latest version then, execute again  `python manage.py makemigration <app name>

Comment: 1.8.7, I tried doing the makemigration and migration again but still the same

Comment: could you please share your migration file `alter query`?

Comment: I updated my question with the new migration file

Comment: Looks like you created another migration file for remove `venue_city`. If this is new table in prod then delete tall these migration files and generate new one

Comment: If this is an existing table in prod then, remove all the migration files from your local since you started this `CharField to a ForeignKey` changes and create new migration file.

Comment: I get django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration venues.0018_auto_20160514_2146 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('venues', '0017_remove_venue_venue_city') - when i do makemigration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111999/discussion-between-tony-kyriakidis-and-anoop).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like you added `null=True` after created migration file. Because `venue_city` is not a nullable field in your migration file

Follow these steps.

```
1) Drop venue_city & venue_country from your local table
3) Delete all the migration files you created for these `CharField to a ForeignKey` change
4) execute `python manage.py makemigrations`
5) execute 'python manage.py migrate'
```

It should work

Comment: Thank you Anoop for all your help in the chatrooms!

Comment: How do you do 1)?

Comment: Just as a quick comment, if you are using something like AWS Elastic Beanstalk it could be easier to simply correct the models, delete the erroneous migrations and makemigrations again.

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem i resolved it by removing the previous migration files.No technical explanation

Comment: just leave the first one[0001].just save the in another folder incase it dosent work.

Comment: did that, It requests dependencies from other nodes when i run makemigrations

Comment: :-( my help ends there.But because migration files are Dependant with previous files.Try inspecting them because the error is a result of conflicting commits to the database

Comment: Definitely don't do this blindly. Could result in some crazy prod db issues.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by just adding `null = True` to both the (automatically generated) migration file that was causing the issue and in the Model. Then `migrate` again and your failed migration will now succeed. As you changed it also in your model, `makemigration` will detect no changes after that.

Answer (score 4):

follow the below steps:-

- add *null=True, blank=True* in Venue model class
  eg: venue_city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
- delete *venues.0016_auto_20160514_2141* migration file from migrations folder in your app
- then run *python manage.py makemigrations*
- then run *python manage.py migrate*

no need to drop table or remove migrations from migration tables

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by below:

1. First delete last migration that face problem
2. Then add like `venue_city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)`
3. Finally use `makemigrations` and `migrate` command

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have a null value in the "venue_city" column.

It seems at the time of defining your model you had not included "null=True".

So it returns null because there is nothing in your 'venue_city" variable. Consider deleting the last migration file and perform another migration using
`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands.

Comment: That's correct, 7+ years ago this was the issue!

Comment: Encountered the issue on 6th of November, 2022. It still does exist

Answer (score 0):

Migration was created but it fails during running. Remove the last migration.

Fix the model definition by adding null=True, default=None if you want it to allow null in database. You need to supply any default value when you are adding column in existing table.

Regenerate the migration (manage.py makemigrations venues) again and migrate (manage.py migrate venues).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open the migration 0016_auto_20160514_2141 and assign some default value there.