# Error during backward migration of DeleteModel in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-migrations

I have two models with one-to-one relationship in Django 1.11 with PostgreSQL. These two models are defined in `models.py` as follows:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    info = JSONField(default={})


class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The auto-created migration file regarding these models is like:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('manager', '0018_some_migration_dependency'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Book',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('info', JSONField(default={})),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='author',
            name='book',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='manager.Book'),
        ),
    ]
```

These implementations have worked successfully. In addition to this migration, we also had some other additional migrations related to other tasks of our project.

Due to our design changes we made today, we decided to move all of the Book info data into our cloud storage. In order to do that, I have implemented a custom migration code as follows:

```py
def push_info_to_cloud(apps, schema_editor):

    Author = apps.get_model('manager', 'Author')
    for author in Author.objects.all():
        if author.book.info is not None and author.book.info != "":

            # push author.book.info to cloud storage

            author.book.info = {}
            author.book.save()


def pull_info_from_cloud(apps, schema_editor):

    Author = apps.get_model('manager', 'Author')
    Book = apps.get_model('manager', 'Book')
    for author in Author.objects.all():

            # pull author.book.info back from cloud storage

            book = Book.objects.create(info=info)
            author.book = book
            author.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('manager', '0024_some_migration_dependency'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(push_info_to_cloud, pull_info_from_cloud)
    ]
```

As the code tells itself, this migrations push each non-null book info data to our cloud storage and replace that with an empty dict in the database. I have tested this migration back and forth and make sure that both the forward and backward migration work successfully.

Then, to get rid of the redundant `Book` table and `book` column in `Author` table, I deleted the `Book` model and the `OneToOneField` book field in the `Author` model and run `manage.py makemigrations`, which resulted in the following auto-generated migration code:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('manager', '0025_some_migration_dependency'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='book',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Book',
        ),
    ]
```

Running `manage.py migrate` did worked. In the end, the `Book` table and the `book` column of the `Author` table are deleted.

Now, the problem is; when I want to migrate back to `0024_some_migration_dependency`, I get the following error during the execution of the latest migration file:

```
  Unapplying manager.0026_auto_20190503_1702...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cagrias/Workspace/Project/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "book_id" contains null values
```

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244199/4665915). To try that, I have manually re-create `Book` model and the OneToOneField `book` field of the `Author` model, by using `blank=True, null=True` parameters this time. But after I apply the migrations above successfully, I got the same exceptions when migrating backwards.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve problem by changing the order of the migrations.

As I mentioned in my question, I have applied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37244199/4665915) by adding `blank=True, null=True` parameters to both `info` and `book` fields. But it's related migration file was created after the migration file that moves our book info to the cloud storage. When I've changed the orders of these two migration files, the problem was solved.